# Custom compare function for qsort multiple types of fields of a struct

Tags: c, qsort

i am trying to use qsort to sort an array of structs based on their fields. im current stuck on how to create the compare function used in qsort.

Struct definition:

```
struct data{
  unsigned char feet;
  double lock;
  short stall;
  short gain;
  char show;
  char country;
  int king;
  unsigned int bunch;
  short strange;
  long int tiger;
  char win[9];
  float ramp;
  char sea;
  unsigned int test;
  short cave;
  char pound;
  float sofa;
};
```

Sorting order (in order of precedence):

```
win in descending order. -
stall in ascending order. -
sea in ascending order. -
pound in ascending order. -
ramp in ascending order. -
test in descending order. -
feet in ascending order. -
show in ascending order. -
sofa in descending order. -
cave in ascending order. -
king in ascending order. -
gain in descending order. -
strange in ascending order. -
country in descending order. -
lock in descending order. -
bunch in ascending order. 
tiger in ascending order.
```

heres the compare function ive tried but i cant seem to get the correct result, sort all of the fields based on precedence :

```
int cmpStructs(const void *a1, const void *a2){
  struct data *a = (struct data *)a1;
  struct data *b = (struct data *)a2;

  if(strcmp(a->win,b->win)>0){
    return -1;
  } else if (strcmp(a->wine,b->wine)<0){
    return 1;
  } else if(a->stall>b->stall){
    return 1;
  } else if(a->stall<b->stall){
    return -1;
  } 
   ///continued if else statements for the rest of the fields

 return 0;
};
```

Comment: start small with 1 field comparison, then gradually add more fields. It's not a good idea to debug with that many comparisons all at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for a start, you're overly complicating things with all those `else if` bits:

```
int cmpStructs(const void *a1, const void *a2){
    struct data *a = (struct data *)a1;
    struct data *b = (struct data *)a2;

    // win, descending.
    if (strcmp(a->win, b->win) > 0) return -1;
    if (strcmp(a->win, b->win) < 0) return  1;

    // stall, ascending.
    if (a->stall > b->stall) return 1;
    if (a->stall < b->stall) return -1;

    // And so on, for each field.

    return 0;
};
```

That way, you can easily comment out large chunks of the comparison "suite" to test each field in turn.

---

You might also consider the use of macro meta-programming to make it easier and more readable, as well as less error-prone since the complexity is localised within the macros, something like (untested, but you should get the idea):

```
#define CMP_STR_ASC(s1, s2) \
    if (strcmp(s1, s2) > 0) return -1; \
    if (strcmp(s1, s2) < 0) return  1;
#define CMP_STR_DESC(s1, s2) CMP_STR_ASC(s2, s1)

#define CMP_VAL_ASC(v1, v2) \
    if (v1 > v2) return -1; \
    if (v1 < v2) return 1;
#define CMP_VAL_DESC(v1, v2) CMP_VAL_ASC(v2, v1)

int cmpStructs(const void *a1, const void *a2){
    struct data *a = (struct data *)a1;
    struct data *b = (struct data *)a2;

    // Very simple rule set, based on the macros.

    CMP_STR_DESC ( a->win,     b->win     )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->stall,   b->stall   )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->sea,     b->sea     )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->pound,   b->pound   )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->ramp,    b->ramp    )
    CMP_VAL_DESC ( a->test,    b->test    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->feet,    b->feet    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->show,    b->show    )
    CMP_VAL_DESC ( a->sofa,    b->sofa    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->cave,    b->cave    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->king,    b->king    )
    CMP_VAL_DESC ( a->gain,    b->gain    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->strange, b->strange )
    CMP_VAL_DESC ( a->country, b->country )
    CMP_VAL_DESC ( a->lock,    b->lock    )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->bunch,   b->bunch   )
    CMP_VAL_ASC  ( a->tiger,   b->tiger   )

    return 0;
};
```

Provided you don't do silly things like wrap these macros inside `if/while` statements without braces, or pass in parameters with side effects, they should be fine as is (function-like macros usually need protection if you wish to be able to use them anywhere but, if you're just using them as a "standalone" statement, you can get away with much simpler ones).

---

In fact, it's this isolation of complexity to the macros that makes it easy to adjust for issues, such as the one raised by DevSolar in a comment (that it's not efficient to run `strcmp` twice).

Because of the isolation, you can easily fix that just by changing the macro to something like:

```
#define CMP_STR_ASC(s1, s2) { \
    int cmpVal = strcmp(s1, s2); \
    if (cmpVal > 0) return -1; \
    if (cmpVal < 0) return  1; \
}
```

Comment: `strcmp()` shouldn't be run twice.

Comment: @DevSolar, I was just illustrating the concept and didn't want to introduce too much complexity. It *can* be run twice, though you're right that it shouldn't because of the inefficiency. I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i was stuck on this for a week and now i understand.